# How to use PowerShell script to remove SSIS packages after checking if the package exists in MSDB or SSISDB?

Tags: sql, powershell, ssis

I am new to Powershell and I am trying to remove a number of SSIS packages that are no longer in use from the remote server. Some are in SSISDB and some are in MSDB. I am trying to create a PowerShell script that checks where(MSDB/SSISDB) the package is and deletes it. Plus, I need to run my SQL query that drops the objects related to that package using PS. Can anyone explain how that is done with a sample PowerShell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## MSDB

Depends on how you want to remove the package. Do you want to invoke an external process (dtutil.exe) or do you want to build/issue SQL queries?

### Command line

[dtutil.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/dtutil-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) is the command line utility for interacting with the MSDB and has been available since the 2005 release.

Sample deletion would look like

```
dtutil.exe /SQL PackageToBeDeleted /DELETE
```

### Stored Procedure

sp_dts_deletepackage (2005) /sp_ssis_deletepackage (2008+) takes as an argument the package name and the folder guid.

```
-- Delete a package in the root folder
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sys_ssis_deletepackage 'MyPackage', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';
```

Older question on how to thread the dts named versions of the metadata to build deletes

[Is it possible to delete an SSIS package from the MSDB database in SQL Server 2005 without DCOM rights?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458052/is-it-possible-to-delete-an-ssis-package-from-the-msdb-database-in-sql-server-20)

### Delete

You can also just delete directly from the table.

```
-- SQL Server 2005
DELETE P FROM dbo.sysdtspackages90 AS P WHERE P.name = 'mypackage'; 
-- SQL Server 2008+
DELETE P FROM dbo.sysssispackages AS P WHERE P.name = 'mypackage';
```

## SSISDB

You can't delete an SSIS *package* from the SSISDB. Packages don't exist in the SSISDB, Folders contain **Projects** which happen to have Packages (and metadata and project parameters and optionally project connection managers). That is all a deployable unit, with an .ispac extension when stored to disk.

Removal of a project is through the stored procedure [delete_project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-stored-procedures/catalog-delete-project-ssisdb-database?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
EXECUTE SSISDB.catalog.delete_project
    @folder_name = 'MyFolder'
,   @project_name = 'MyProject';
```